# Can i submit another US visa application if i need to change the target arrival date to US?

Tags: visas, usa

Pls help. I had submitted an application but could not get an earlier interview sched fit to the target date of arrival. I had already paid for the visa fee. can I send another application changing the target date?

Thank you.

Comment: I don’t know if it would matter, but what was your intended travel date and the reason for the trip? For example, if the premise was to attend a wedding but the interview date is after the wedding date your application might be rejected / refused on the grounds that the reason for travel was no longer valid.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any reason why you would need to submit a new visa application. You can just let the consular officer know at the interview that you had to change your travel dates.